# Fetch objects having the same value for a given property from CoreData?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, dictionary, nsdate

I want to fetch persons having the same birthday from CoreData ?

or in general if I have array of persons `[Person]` where `Person` class as follow

```
Person {
 var name: String
 var birthday: NSDate
}
```

and I want to group the persons based on birthday not birthdate, so I want `[NSDate:[Person]]`
dictionary.

so could anyone please help me with this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` is precise down to the 10th of a millisecond, so first you will have to make sure all dates have the same hours and seconds.

The best way to group in Core Data is with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can use the date as the `sectionNameKeyPath` and it will group automatically for you. The items in the fetched results controller can be easily accessed with index paths, very useful for table views.